# Tensorflow object detection API: weird result

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I've use pre-trained ssd mobilenet v2 model and fine tune on my Drone dataset. I followed their tutorial. I have 300 images for train and 90 images for test. After 190k global step, I test my model but result is so weird. It can detect the drone but it will always detect something at the bottom of every images.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knyhy.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc3lm.png)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fplfB.png)

[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjpJP.png)

[image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUzgI.png)

Why is it so?
Thank you

Comment: Did you try a different model architecture? What are your training and testing errors? Do you get the same problem on images in the training set? What is your training configuration?

Comment: I've tried faster rcnn inception, the result is better but my work needs fast processing so I decided to use ssd mobile. The total loss is about 1.5. Yes, it's same problem with my training set images. My training configuration is from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs file name "ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config" I just changed batch size from 24 to 2 and some train/test directory.

Comment: So it's not overfitting since you have the same problem on the training set. I suggest you monitor the training with Tensorboard so that you can see more details about the errors as the training proceed. You can also try `ssd_inception` which is faster than `rcnn` but stronger than `ssd_mobilenet`.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you very much.